# Formatting difference between IE/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, formatting

I'm trying to understand why the following produces different results in IE/Firefox and Chrome:

```
<a href="#">ABC <span style="position: absolute;">XYZ</span></a>
```

In IE7 and Firefox 3.6, "ABC" is underlined while "XYZ" is not, and there is no visible space between them, i.e. they are run together as "ABCXYZ".

In Chrome 9, the entire string is underlined, and there is a space between them, i.e. "ABC XYZ".

Obviously they are each handling the `position: absolute` differently, so I'm trying to figure out why. This example is distilled from a larger piece of code where absolute positioning is necessary, so I'm trying to get IE/Firefox and Chrome to all look the same.

I've tried to specify `text-decoration: none` on the span to get rid of the underline on "XYZ", but Chrome just ignores that.

Comment: Have you tried a `&nbsp;` instead of the whitespace after 'ABC'? That might help with the spacing issue.

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately I'm trying to understand the underlining more than the spacing, since I'm using the absolute positioning to move the span exactly where I want it. I posted the spacing thing as another example of how the different browsers rendered the same code differently, but that's definitely one way to force the spacing to behave.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` with the span?

`position:absolute;` may have issues when used with an `inline` element (which is the default for `<span>`)

Comment: I used that but no effect. It works fine in firefox but not in chrome.